# как собрать проэкт javaFX в IntelliJ IDEA (community edition)?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

Дамы и Господа, написал первый проэкт на javaFX и не понимаю как с него сделать рабочий jar, чтобы его можно было запускать и всех неверящих корефанов тыкать носом. Ибо только учусь.

В project structure создал артефакт модуля с зависимостями; указал класc с методом main. Далее Build -> Build artifact.

Появляеться jar-ник, но он не запускаеться (ни 2-я щелчками, ни запустить с помощью java.exe). Пробовал создавать как обычный jar так и javaFX Application.

В идеале был бы благодарен, если бы дали ссылку на простой гид, где объясняеться все для таких как я. Спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо создать артефакт и при его build будет сгенерирован JAR.

```
1. Project Settings, вкладка Artifacts. Нажимаем [+], в выпавшем меню выбираем JAR.
2. В панели слева - содержимое JAR-файла, в панели справа - содержимое проекта. Перетаскиваем справа налево все, что хотим включить в JAR.
3. Указываем имя для файла и директорию назначения над панелями
4. Нажимаем на кнопку create manifest под левой панелью, создаем manifest.mf. При этом IDE спросит Main class и classpath для указания в манифесте.
5. Не забудем поставить галочку "Build on make" над панелями
6. Теперь в меню Build есть команда сборки артефакта
```

Comment: У меня проект с одной подключенной библиотекой. Idea распаковывает эту библиотеку и непосредственно проект в общий jar архив. Нужно ли что то прописывать в classpath и что именно?

Comment: @uncleMichael попробуйте так создать - будут ошибки, напишите

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я до утра сидел, не мог собрать проект. В гугле все это время искал, не нашел толковой информации по этому поводу.